# How would i add textures to textButtons in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm new to libGDX I've been trying to follow tutorials on how to create buttons and add textures to them however I am really struggling with it. How would I add textures to the continue and back buttons? I only have the png image and a .pack file for the textures

Also if anyone would be able to suggest some ways I can change the font of the labels I have for my buttons e.g. lbl_ip

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen {
    private Viewport viewport;
    private Stage stage;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private MainGame game;
    
    private Label lbl_ip;
    private Label lbl_name;
    private Label lbl_back;
    
    private LabelStyle lbl_style;
    
    private Skin txt_skin;
    
    private TextButtonStyle btn_style;
    
    private TextField txt_ip;
    private TextField txt_name;
    //private TextField txt_back;
    
    private Button btn_confirm;
    private Button btn_back;
    
    public static String ip = "localhost"; // change with user input
    public static String name = "Player 1";
    public static String back = "<---";

    
    public MenuScreen(MainGame game) {
        this.game = game;
        viewport = new FitViewport(MainGame.V_WIDTH/6, MainGame.V_HEIGHT/6, new OrthographicCamera());
        stage = new Stage(viewport, ((MainGame) game).batch);
        
        lbl_style = new Label.LabelStyle();
        lbl_style.font = new BitmapFont();
        
        txt_skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
        
        btn_style = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        btn_style.font = new BitmapFont();
        
        Table table = new Table();
        table.top();
        table.setFillParent(true);
        
        lbl_ip = new Label("please enter an IP address:" , lbl_style);
        lbl_name = new Label("enter your name: " , lbl_style);
        lbl_back = new Label("Return to Main Menue", lbl_style);
        
        txt_ip = new TextField(ip, txt_skin);
        txt_name = new TextField(name, txt_skin);
        //txt_back = new TextField(back, txt_skin);
        
        
        btn_confirm = new TextButton("confirm", btn_style);
        btn_back = new TextButton("<--", btn_style);
        
        table.add(lbl_ip).expandX();
        table.add(txt_ip).width(200);
        table.row();
        table.add(lbl_name).expandX();
        table.add(txt_name).width(200);
        table.row();
        //table.add(lbl_back).expandX();
        table.add(btn_back);
        //table.add(txt_back).width(200);
        table.row();
        table.add(btn_confirm);
        table.row();
        
        stage.addActor(table);
        
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    }
    
    private void buttonHandler() {
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ENTER)) {
            /*
            game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));
            */
            txt_ip.setTextFieldListener(new TextField.TextFieldListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void keyTyped(TextField textField, char c) {
                    ip = textField.getText();
                }
            });
            txt_name.setTextFieldListener(new TextField.TextFieldListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void keyTyped(TextField textField, char c) {
                    name = textField.getText();
                }
            });

            new MPClient(txt_ip.getText(), txt_name.getText(), game);
            dispose();
        
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,  0,  0 , 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        stage.draw();
        stage.act(delta);
        
        buttonHandler();
    }

    
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ImageTextButton` for that. You need to provide it with `ImageTextButtonStyle`, which is easy to create (you need to assign its `imageUp` property, other properties can be null).

As far as label font goes, you need to create a new `LabelStyle` and assign it a new `BitmapFont`. An example:

```
Label lab = new Label("This is the text", new LabelStyle(myFont, Color.RED));
```

"myfont" is a `BitmapFont`.
Here is a real-world example how to create a `BitmapFont`:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;
FreeTypeFontParameter parameter;

generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/nidsans-webfont.ttf"));
parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 12;
parameter.minFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;
parameter.magFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;
myfont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the -style- associated with the widget. And you may want to make a new style per widget rather than sharing a style across all (because that would update all widgets with the new background)

```
LabelStyle newLabelStyle = new LabelStyle(originalLabel.getStyle());
tobeChangedLabel.setStyle(newLabelStyle);
newLabelStyle.background = new Image( //however you like to make the image
```

Changing the font is somewhat tricky... as the fonts are baked into the style as bitmaps (for rendering speed). You may find that given you don't like the background of your style, or even the font, that you might want to use a different skin. You can make your own or use one from here.
https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-skins

If you have to dynamically choose font you can dynamically build your bitmaps of rendered fonts with gdx-freetype-font-manager
https://jitpack.io/p/1nt3g3r/gdx-freetype-font-manager